# use do while to perform a function with a variable in php

Tags: php, do-while

I want to read a css file and extract the urls inside it and repeat this function to the urls with the css extension. How can I reach it

This is my code:

```
$fileURL = 'http://example.com/css/style.css';
somefunction($fileURL);

function somefunction($cssFileURL) {

    do {
        $cssFile =  file_get_contents($cssFileURL);

        //extract css urls
        preg_match_all('/url\((.*)\)/U', $cssFile, $matches);

        $cssURLs = $matches[1];

        foreach ($cssURLs as $cssURL) {

            $cssURL = str_replace(array('\'', '"'), '', $cssURL);

            $fileInfo = pathinfo('http://example.com/css/' . $cssURL);

            // do something ...
        }

    } while ($fileInfo['extension'] == 'css');
}
```

I know that there has to be the file url to be submitted before getting the file contents. But, I really got confused to do it. Any help is appreciated.